# Legality of using delete-expression on a pointer to an object of class type with a trivial destructor/scalar type whose lifetime has ended

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Is the following code legal?

```
struct S
{};
int main()
{
    S* p = new S;
    p->~S();
    delete p;
}
```

The standard rules at [[basic.life#6]](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#6):

> Before the lifetime of an object has started but after the storage which the object will occupy has been allocated24 or, after the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the object occupied is reused or released, any pointer that represents the address of the storage location where the object will be or was located may be used but only in limited ways. For an object under construction or destruction, see [class.cdtor]. Otherwise, such a pointer refers to allocated storage ([basic.stc.dynamic.allocation]), and using the pointer as if the pointer were of type void* is well-defined. Indirection through such a pointer is permitted but the resulting lvalue may only be used in limited ways, as described below. The program has undefined behavior if:

> (6.1) — the object will be or was of a class type with a non-trivial destructor and the pointer is used as the operand of a delete-expression,

> (6.2) — the pointer is used to access a non-static data member or call a non-static member function of the object

[basic.life#6.1] doesn't apply, so this code seems to be legal because `S` has a trivial destructor.

However, according to [basic.life#6.2], this code is illegal because the delete-expression calls the destructor of the `S` object, which is a non-static member function of it.

**EDIT:** According to [[class.dtor#19]](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.dtor#19), it's also illegal.

Which should I listen to? Maybe [basic.life#6.2], because [basic.life#6.1] doesn't stipulate that it must be legal to do so for classes with trivial destructor.

The conclusion is that it's illegal.

However, after replacing `S` with a scalar type, things seem to be different:

```
#include <memory>
int main()
{
    char* p = new char;
    std::destroy_at(p);
    delete p;
}
```

This will make a pseudo-destructor call to the `char` object pointed to by `p`, which will end its lifetime, according to [[expr.call#5]](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.call#5):

> If the postfix-expression names a pseudo-destructor (in which case the postfix-expression is a possibly-parenthesized class member access), the function call destroys the object of scalar type denoted by the object expression of the class member access ([expr.ref], [basic.life]).

[basic.life#6.1] still doesn't apply.

But the difference is that [basic.life#6.2] doesn't apply either, because there is no non-static member function called for the `char` object (`char` isn't a class after all).

The conclusion is that it's legal.

**Why?**

Comment: *... this code is illegal...* Why?  Your analysis does not jibe with the statements in the standard.

Comment: @Eljay Can you point out why it doesn't jibe with the statements in the standard?

Comment: Because your claim to it being illegal is contrary to the statements in the standard.

Comment: For  [basic.life#6.2] you assume that invoking a trivial destructor counts as a invoking a non-static member function. I don't think that is true. Seeing how a trivial destructor by definition does nothing, it is either not invoked or doesn't count as a member function. Not sure right now which one it is

Comment: Note also [expr.delete] clause 6: "the delete-expression will invoke the destructor (if
any)". There is no destructor, so it is not invoked

Comment: _according to [basic.life#6.2], this code is illegal because the delete-expression calls the destructor of the `S` object_ Does [expr.delete] say that the destructor is called using a pointer?

Comment: https://eel.is/c++draft/class.dtor#19.sentence-1 applies to the class object case

Comment: _Is this asymmetric behavior an issue?_ Opinion-based question.

Comment: @Language Lawyer Well, I admit my wording wasn't good enough...I don't know how the destructor can be called without that pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that there is a wording defect. Either your code is intended to be legal, or it's not. If it is intended to be legal, then [basic.life]/6.2 should have an exception for a trivial destructor. If it's not intended to be legal, then the words "with a non-trivial destructor" should be struck from [basic.life]/6.1 because even if the destructor is trivial, the inevitable destructor call will violate p6.2.

I suspect that it was intended to be legal, because there's no point in preserving the explicit exception in the case of `delete` if not to prevent breaking code that was, in fact, calling `delete` on objects with trivial destructors that are outside their lifetimes.

[N2762](https://wg21.link/N2762) removed the trivial destructor exception for all the other UB-causing operations on pointers to objects outside their lifetimes, but conspicuously kept it for *delete-expression*s. This suggests that there was a need to keep this exception in the language in order to avoid breaking code.

Most likely the reason why the second bullet was not also changed to make an exception for a trivial destructor call is that the authors forgot that a *delete-expression* *does* call the destructor even if it's trivial. They might have assumed that `delete` was specified to skip the destructor call if it would be trivial.

(Note also that in C++98 through C++17, your `S` object's lifetime is not ended by the destructor call anyway because [basic.life]/1 specified that a destructor call ends the lifetime of the object only if it is non-trivial; this was changed in C++20 by [CWG2256](https://wg21.link/cwg2256). However, due to N2762, in C++11 and later, if an object's lifetime has not yet *started* because it has nontrivial initialization, we can run into an issue that is similar to the one described by the OP.)

I think it's worth filing a defect report about this, though I'm not sure what the outcome will be. So much time has elapsed since N2762 that I would imagine the committee would actually want to consider whether the exception for trivial destructors ought to be eliminated at this point (*i.e.*, fixing p6.1 instead of p6.2); after all, the resolution of CWG2256 may also have broken some code, but it was probably code of the sort that has become increasingly rare over the years since C++ diverged from C.

Comment: It's not clear to me what's the use of avoiding breaking code, it's perfectly fine to call `operator delete` after destruction instead of delete-expression.

Comment: _even if the destructor is trivial, the inevitable destructor call will violate p6.2_ If you do it manually, using a pointer, then yes, but [expr.delete] does not say it uses a pointer to call the destructor

Comment: _in C++98 through C++17 … [basic.life]/1 specified that a destructor call ends the lifetime of the object only if it is non-trivial_ On the other OTOH, C++98 [class.dtor]/14: «Once a destructor is invoked for an object, the object no longer exists; the behavior is undefined if the destructor is invoked for an object whose lifetime has ended» (where «no longer exists» likely means «its lifetime ends»). No exception for trivial destructors.

Comment: @Language Lawyer I don't know how the destructor can be called without that pointer. Even so, the destructor is still called via a glvalue that refers to the original object, in this case [basic.life]/7.2 applies.

Comment: @Blackteahamburger _[basic.life]/7.2 applies_ To what? To [expr.delete]? I do not see it saying it calls the destructor using a pointer or glvalue. _I don't know how the destructor can be called without that pointer_ Implementation can do what you can't.

Comment: @Language Lawyer Well, you are right. But implementation can still call the destructor using a pointer, so it should be undefined behavior.

Comment: @Blackteahamburger The potential issue with "breaking code" is not because anyone *needs* to evaluate a *delete-expression* on a pointer to an object whose lifetime has ended. It is because perhaps there *already exists* code that does so, and changing the language so that such code continues to compile but silently exhibits undefined behaviour might be dangerous.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I agree that the implementation is not constrained by the language rules that apply to expressions of the form `p->~S()`. However, I think that the implementation certainly "uses" the pointer in the sense that it only knows what object you're trying to delete by virtue of the fact that you pass the pointer as an operand.